# Pandas join index with multiindex without merge

Tags: python, pandas, concatenation

I have an index with all values I want present in resulting dataframe (`df3`):

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(['aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'dd', 'ee']).set_index(0)

------------------------------------
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: [aa, bb, cc, dd, ee]
```

I'm trying to join this index with another df (`df2`):

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame([['bb', 'xxx', 777, 888], ['dd', 'yyy', 999, 0]]).set_index([0, 1])

------------------------------------
           2    3
0  1
bb xxx  777  888
dd yyy  999    0
```

I can do this with `merge` but it's slow (this is the end result I want, without using merge):

```
df3 = df1.reset_index().merge(df2.reset_index(), how='left').set_index([0, 1])

------------------------------------
             2      3
0  1
aa NaN    NaN    NaN
bb xxx  777.0  888.0
cc NaN    NaN    NaN
dd yyy  999.0    0.0
ee NaN    NaN    NaN
```

I want to use `join` but I'm unable to merge the indexes, df1 index gets dropped even though I specified `how='outer'` which should keep both indexes.

```
df3 = df1.join(df2, how='outer')

------------------------------------
           2    3
0  1
bb xxx  777  888
dd yyy  999    0
```

Ideas on how to combine the dataframes using join or concat or anything faster than merge?

Comment: `df1.join(df2.reset_index(level=1)).set_index([1], append=True)`?

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. You could add it as an answer so I'd checkmark.